# missing file in R

Tags: r, bash, sed

There are files I have produced as output of jobs on a cluster. Every file contains a table with dim 100, 3. 
I should have 1414 files - but there are only 1413. Now I want to check which file is missing . They are all labelled like

```
2 2 _ from : to
```

like

```
2 2 _ 1 : 100
2 2 _ 101 : 200
2 2 _ 201: 300
```

Can I somehow check which of the 1414 files is missing? So a solution in R is obviously ideal but am also happy if there is a bash thing

R would be like

```
list.files(pattern="2 2 _")->ww
library(gtools)
mixedsort(ww)->ww
```

but still don't know which files are missing then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

- Use `gsub` to throw away the "2 2 _ from :" part.
- Then `as.numeric` to get a vector `v` of numbers 100,200,300, etc.
- Then use `which(diff(sort(v))>100)` to find the hole(s).

*Example:*

```
> ww <- c( "2 2 _ 1:100", "2 2 _ 101:200", "2 2 _ 201:300", "2 2 _ 501:600", "2 2 _ 401:500" )

> v <- sapply( ww, function(x){ as.numeric(gsub("[^:]*:","",x)) } )

> which(diff(sort(v))>100)
2 2 _ 401:500 
            3 
>
```

This means that "2 2 _ 301:400" is missing. "2 2 _ 401:500" is the first file after the hole.

*Example with two holes:*

```
> ww <- c( "2 2 _ 1:100", "2 2 _ 701:800", "2 2 _ 201:300", "2 2 _ 501:600", "2 2 _ 401:500", "2 2 _ 101:200" )

> v <- sapply( ww, function(x){ as.numeric(gsub("[^:]*:","",x)) } )

> which(diff(sort(v))>100)
2 2 _ 401:500 2 2 _ 701:800 
            3             5 
>
```

This means that "2 2 _ 301:400" and 2 2 _ 601:700"" are missing

The vector `ww` of file names need not be sorted. Sorting in done by `sort(v)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
z <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("[[:space:]]", "", ww), "_|:"))
```

you should now have z, that looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "22" "1"   "100"
[2,] "22" "101" "200"
[3,] "22" "201" "300"
```

then you can subset by those where the second column is not equal to the previous third column plus one:

```
z[which(as.numeric(z[,2]) != as.numeric(lag(z[,3])) + 1), ]
```

Comment: This will fail if the labels are initially sorted lexicographically and there are numbers > 1000 in the third column unless you convert all data in `z` into numeric form and sort the matrix.

Comment: if run after the `mixedsort` from op it should be fine - or yeah otherwise there need be an `as.numeric` and sort in there